# Animate absolute positioned div outwards on both sides of parent

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a structure like this:

```css
.sectors-column-right {
  float: right;
  width: 800px;
  height: 796px;
  position: relative;
}
.sectors-modal {
  background: #fff;
  width: 764px;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 58px;
  right: 18px;
  z-index: 1111;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="sectors-column-right">
  <div class="sectors-column">
  </div>
  <div class="sectors-column">
  </div>
  <div class="sectors-modal">
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make `.sectors-modal` animate outwards (on both sides at the same time), say, on click? Can I do it with only CSS, or do I need JavaScript?

Comment: mention the `left` and `right` values in negative..

Comment: can show us what you want using image, I think that will help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Remove the width on `.selectors-modal`
- Place `left: 0` and `right: 0` (or positive values if you want a gap) on `.selectors-modal` to stretch it
- Give `.selectors-modal` a suitable `transition`
- On hover (or click with jQuery) change the left and right values in the negative. The transition gives a smooth animation.

Ensure there is space for the expansion. I have made space in this example with `left: -200px` on the parent.

### Example — On Hover

```css
.sectors-column-right {
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  height: 796px;
  position: relative;
  background: #F00;
  left: -200px;
}
.sectors-modal {
  background: #fff;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 58px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: all 1s;
}
.sectors-modal:hover {
  right: -200px;
  left: -200px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="sectors-column-right">
  <div class="sectors-column">
  </div>
  <div class="sectors-column">
  </div>
  <div class="sectors-modal">
  </div>
</div>
```

### Example — On Click (using jQuery)

```js
$( ".sectors-modal" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).toggleClass( "expanded" );
});
```

```css
.sectors-column-right {
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  height: 796px;
  position: relative;
  background: #F00;
  left: -200px;
}
.sectors-modal {
  background: #fff;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 58px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: all 1s;
}
.expanded {
  right: -200px;
  left: -200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sectors-column-right">
  <div class="sectors-column">
  </div>
  <div class="sectors-column">
  </div>
  <div class="sectors-modal">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

remove `position:relative` from parent then the `position:absolute` `div` will take the positioned values (`left,`right`) from the`document`

```css
.sectors-column-right {
  float: right;
  width: 800px;
  height: 796px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.sectors-modal {
  background: #fff;
  background: grey;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 58px;
  right: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  z-index: 1111;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="sectors-column-right">
  <div class="sectors-column"></div>
  <div class="sectors-column"></div>
  <div class="sectors-modal">width</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I wasn't clear in my question. I meant to animate outwards (on both sides at the same time).

Answer (score 0):

```css
.sectors-column-right { position: relative; width: 100%; }
.sectors-modal{ width: auto; margin-left: 160px; border: 1px solid #000; }
.sectors-column{ width: 145px; position: absolute; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; border: 1px solid #F00; }
```

```html
<div class="sectors-column-right">
    <div class="sectors-column">
    </div>
    <div class="sectors-column">
    </div>
    <div class="sectors-modal"></div>
</div>
```